# Java data migration for Oracle and MS SQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, data-migration, flyway

I need a data migration framework that enables to execute java code for using hibernate and spring.
Currently, i'm using flyway (we have both Oracle and MS SQL), this is not very comfortable because it requires to write SQL for each database we are using - 2 SQL script for every change(and SQL are harder to write when the query involves logic). Is there any other framework with which I can use my spring beans and hibernate ?

Comment: Have you tried injecting Hibernate into flyway's java-based migration: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java.html ? It should be possible.

Comment: @user3707125, No, but this is not a good solution for me, it requires using JDBC and the spring context is not available so I cannot reuse my DAOs and services for changing the data in the DB.

Comment: Entity Manager Factory Configuration.

The one thing to take note in the Entity Manager Factory’s configuration is the depends on property that is set to reference the Flyway bean. What this does is to ensure that the Flyway bean is always created before the Entity Manager Factory bean. Which is what you would want as you need Flyway to already have been created, do its thing before the Entity Manager Factory kicks in. In the JavaConfig this is specified using the @DependsOn... [link]http://blog.trifork.com/2014/12/09/integrating-flywaydb-in-a-spring-framework-application/comment-page-1/